# How to get image pop ups in QGIS using oracle blob field with image?

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial

I have a point feature in oracle database which has as attribute a blob field that have image inside for every point feature taken in field.

Is there anyway that i can decode and display it on a popup display in Qgis?

I can do hyperlink or popup display if the image files are outside database as file and their path as attribute but i want to know if they can be read directly from oracle blob field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is any direct method to display the Blob field as pop-up in QGIS. You need to code a little to acheive this.

Do the following procedure to go half way.

1. Load the Spatial table into QGIS using Add Oracle Spatial Layer.
2. Right-Click on the layer and click on properties.

[image: Layer Properties]

3. Go to **Actions** tab. Here you can choose from the default action like creating a Java jar file which reads the first argument as unique serial number of your spatial table, retrieves blob as image and displays. (Click on **Add default actions** for more options).

[image: Add Action]

4. Now click **Run Feature action** button and select **Run an application** Option. Now when you click on any feature it opens that application and adds the respective unique serial number as argument and displays the image, of course not as a pop-up but as a seperate application.

[image]

You can also do this using a web application and pass the unique serial number as a parameter and choose open action in Action tab. In this you need not create any JRE or any environmental variables.

Hope it is helpful. All the Best.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a blob/bytea variable you can make a virtual field where you convert the blob to 64 bit using `to_base64( "photo_blob" )`

[image: snip of blob photo]

Then in the `display` tab you can add your HTML referring to it `<img width='500' src='data:image/png;base64,[% "photo_blob_64bit" %]'>`:

[image: snip of setting display value in layer properties]

Then you can make these appear with the hover over using "show map tips":

[image: show map tips]