# Evaluating images in HTML widget using QGIS

Tags: qgis, javascript, html

I would like to have images displayed in my HTML widget.

Unfortunately, the initial script generated by QGIS doesn't work.

```
  <tr>
  <td>Images</td>
  <td><script>document.write(expression.evaluate("\"Image\""));</script></td>
  </tr>
```

It comes with the text string only.

I found some solution at [Display photo stored as blob in GPKG](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350541/display-photo-stored-as-blob-in-gpkg) but it shows a Python function instead of a front-end solution.

I need my image related to the feature, but not in the HTML display section, but in HTML widget - see
[Show images related to features in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237156/show-images-related-to-features-in-qgis)

There are some solutions here but don't work in my case:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910137/how-to-document-write-within-an-image-src-string-doesnt-get-parsed
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22503908/html-is-img-src-scriptsome-javascript-script-allowed
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116967/img-src-tags-and-javascript

Is there any way to show in the HTML widget the image related to my object?

[image]

Even if I place the link to static image, the problem is the same:

```
 <tr>
 <td>Images</td>
 <td><img src = "Supporting_Docs\Images\S1.jpg"  width="300" height="225" 
 alt="Alias Name"/></td>
 </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Does inserting a start and end tag for table help? <table> </table> See: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1

Answer (score 4):

For a static image, you can try the following. Note that I am using an absolute local path with **3** slashes.

```
<div>Image: <img src = 'file:///D:\temp\50k.png'  width='300' height='225' alt='Alias Name'></img></div>
```

For a dynamic image, you need to build the path. In my example the field `photo` contains a path like `D:\temp\50k.png`

```
<script>document.write(expression.evaluate("'<div>Image: <img src = \"file:///'|| photo ||'\"  width=\"300\" height=\"225\" alt=\"Alias Name\"/></div>'"));</script>
```

The HTML widget it very powerful... but is also very sensitive to quotes, escaping, new lines etc. My tip is to start with a very simple output and to build around it, making and testing one change at a time.
It is also useful to do a right click on the preview + `inspect` and to compare with the input (ex: the path `D:\temp\50k.png` was changed for `file:///D:emp(k.png` if I write the true image path instead of reading it from a field, pointing to escaping issues)

To finish, you can try to move part of the html out of the `<script>` section.... be very careful how the output(s) are appended to each others.

Comment: The first one is fine. The second one doesn't work.  My image path is related to the project. I tried to put both a full path from my disk as well as the related to my project <img src = \"file:///Supporting_Docs\Images\'|| Image ||'\"  width=\"300\" height=\"225\" alt=\"Alias Name\"/></div>'" is that alright then?

Comment: @MKR I don't know for the relative path. The example I provided do work here, so try the `inspect` trick to see how your path is interpreted