# How to display movies stored as Geopackage blobs?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, video

**Background:**

At 3.20.1 I have a standalone Geopackage table that contains a Blob field.  For most of the table's records the Blob contains a .jpg image.  However, some of the records contain a .mov or .mp4 movie in the Blob.

I have successfully displayed the Blob .jpg images using the HTML Form Widget answer provided by *jgrocha* in [Display photo stored as blob in GPKG](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350541/display-photo-stored-as-blob-in-gpkg).  Now I would like to find an approach that would display the videos as well.  Reviewing the QGIS docs, as well as a search through SE GIS turned up nothing.

**Question:**

How to display videos stored as Geopackage Blobs in QGIS?

Comment: there is a plugin for QGIS named QGIS Full Motion Video. Links:  https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QGIS_FMV/   https://all4gis.github.io/QGISFMV/