# Image Interactions (Right-Click Options) in QGIS HTML Widget

Tags: qgis

I have followed the instructions in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350541/display-photo-stored-as-blob-in-gpkg/385918#385918?newreg=b0d1295d96a642c9acf6048b361ddbf7) to view photos in QGIS from our PostgreSQL database. However, I encountered an issue when attempting to interact with the images. When right-clicking on the image in QGIS, I see options to Open Image, Save Image, Copy Image, and Copy Image Address. Unfortunately, selecting any of these options does not yield any results.

If it is not possible to make these options functional, is there a way to disable the panel that appears when someone right-clicks on the image?

[image]