# QGIS How to display PDF saved as BLOB

Tags: qgis, geopackage, pdf, html, qgis-widget

I have a file where locations have photos and PDF attachments stored as BLOBs. Using the HTML widget, I have gotten it to show the photos as per a [previous answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350541/display-photo-stored-as-blob-in-gpkg) on this forum.

I'm not sure how to do the same for the PDFs. I have very limited knowledge in both QGIS and code so quite frankly I have no idea what I'm doing.

Nothing I've tried has worked. This is the furthest I've gotten:

```
fileName=(expression.evaluate("\"ATT_NAME\""));
fileType=fileName.slice(-3)

if(fileType == "jpg"){
    document.write(expression.evaluate(" '<img width=\"100%\" src=' || '\"data:image/png;base64,' || to_base64(\"DATA\") || '\">' "));
}
else{
    document.write(expression.evaluate(" '<object data=' || '\"data:application/pdf;base64,' || to_base64(\"DATA\") || '\" type='application/pdf'>' "));
}
```

How can I display a PDF?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! Please add a link to the previous answer that was helpful to solve the photo part of your problem. This allows others to better understand your issue.